# G29 Auto Grid Leveling Doesn't Do Anything

Tags: marlin, creality-ender-3, bltouch

I have an Ender 3 Pro, recently added a BLTouch v3, flashed a bootloader, and I'm now attempting to configure TH3D U1.R2.15 firmware.

I have only modified configuration.h, haven't touched any other file, and configured it using the inline comments as a guide.

Everything seems to work ok, apart from it doesn't do a grid/mesh level before the print. G29 has been added just after G28 in Cura in the Start gcode box.

When I print something, this happens:

1. Bed + hotend heats up.
2. X/Y get homed.
3. Nozzle moves to the center.
4. BLTouch slowly comes down to probe the bed twice to set the level based on that one single center point.
5. Primes the filament and begins the print...

I'm not sure what the correct sequence is but I would have thought it should probe 9 points in a grid as I have set `#define EZABL_POINTS 3`.

Have I missed something in the config?

**configuration.h** (have omitted all other printer sections to allow stackexchange to accept the rest of the file)

```
/**
* ************** How to use this firmware - READ THIS, yes actually read this. *********************************
*
* Uncomment means removing the 2 // in front of #define.
* 
* FLASHING NOTES:
* ALL slicers (Simplify3D, Cura, Slic3r, etc) or anything else that connects to the COM port must be CLOSED for the firmware to be flash.
* If anything is connected to the COM port when flashing it will fail, typically "access denied" is listed in the error section of the Arduino IDE.
* You MUST use the Included Arduino IDE to flash the firmware if on Windows and if you are on a Mac or Linux follow the guide in our knowledgebase to setup your IDE to work with the firmware.
* 
* EZABL SETUP NOTES: 
* If you have EZABL uncomment the mount you are using with the printer. 
* If you have a custom/unsupported mount uncomment #define CUSTOM_MOUNT and enter your offsets 
* below in the CUSTOM MOUNT section. Refer to the EZABL guide to get your offsets.
* 
* STEP 1:
* Select the correct board from the tools menu for the printer you are flashing.
* Read the printer title for the model you are flashing, it will show what board to select.
*
* STEP 2:
* Uncomment the printer you want to flash. The printers are sorted A-Z by brand name.
* If you are using the Creality Dual board with the Ender 3/Ender 5/CR-20 then read the specific section below in that printer section on how to do this.
*
* STEP 3: 
* Select the COM port your printer is on from the Tools menu. If you do not see the COM port try
* downloading the latest drivers from the manufacturer or TH3D site on our knowledgebase.
* 
* STEP 4:
* Verify you have the correct board selected, printer model uncommented, and if you are using EZOUT and/or EZABL
* the lines you need to use them are also uncommented.
*
* STEP 5:
* Once you have your settings verified click the arrow in the upper left to upload to the board.
*
* STEP 6:
* Reset your eeprom. You can send M502 then M500 to reset the EEPROM OR on the printer LCD go to 
* Control > Reset EEPROM to clear out the EEPROM to defaults.
*
* BOOTLOADER FLASHING NOTES:
* For flashing your bootloader with an Uno make sure to select Arduino as ISP for the programmer
* 
* There are other features in the TH3D Extras section so look there for V6 Hotend,
* Bootscreen settings, Titan Extruder and more. You only need to edit this file.
* 
* ERROR NOTES:
* If you get errors flashing READ the message it gives you and double check that you selected
* the correct board from the Tools menu in Arduino. Turn off any AV systems and reboot the computer.
* 
* COMMUNITY REQUESTED FEATURES NOTE:
* All features in the community requested features section are provided as-is with no support from TH3D.
*/

#ifndef CONFIGURATION_H
#define CONFIGURATION_H
#define CONFIGURATION_H_VERSION 010109

//===========================================================================
//============================ TH3D Configuration ===========================
//===========================================================================

// ONLY UNCOMMENT THINGS IN ONE PRINTER SECTION!!! IF YOU HAVE MULTIPLE MACHINES FLASH THEM ONE AT A TIME.

//===========================================================================
// Creality Ender 3 Options - Select 'Sanguino 1284p' from Tools > Board
//===========================================================================
#define ENDER3

// If you are using our EZOut V1/V2 (connected to LCD header) filament sensor kit please follow the install guide
// and then uncomment the #define EZOUT_ENABLE line below.
// Do NOT ever connect our filament sensor without the supplied adapter board.
//#define EZOUT_ENABLE

// EZABL Probe Mounts (Ender 3 uses the same mounts as CR-10)
//#define CR10_OEM
//#define CR10_VOLCANO
//#define CR10_V6HEAVYDUTY
//#define TM3DAERO
//#define TM3DAERO_EXTENDED
//#define PETSFANG  //This is the RIGHT mounted version - if using the left mount please use the CUSTOM_PROBE option.
#define CUSTOM_PROBE

// TMC2208 Creality Board Setting - uncomment this to set the driver type if you are using the TMC Creality board
//#define TMC_CREALITY_BOARD

//=================================================================================================
// README - THE BELOW SETTINGS ARE ONLY FOR USING THE CR-10S DUAL BOARD WITH THE ENDER 3
// DO NOT UNCOMMENT THE ABOVE #define ENDER3 LINE IF USING THE DUAL BOARD
// Select 'Arduino Mega 2560' from Tools > Board - NOT Sanguino
//
// To use the Ender 3 LCD with the CR-10S dual board board connect the LCD cable to EXP1 on the 
// CR-10S board but rotate it 180 degrees. The LCD end of the cable goes to EXP3 on the Ender 3 LCD.
// You will have to force it into the EXP1 but it will fit and work.
// 
// EZABL and EZOut support are still supported just use the lines above this comment section.
//=================================================================================================
//#define ENDER3_DUALBOARD

// Dual Extruder Board Options - The below options are for use with the TH3D CR-10S Board with dual extruder support.

// If you are using a single hotend with the 2 into 1 adapter OR mixing nozzle uncomment the below line
//#define DUAL_EXTRUDER_SINGLE_HOTEND

// If you are using a dual hotend with dual nozzles uncomment the below line
//#define DUAL_HOTEND_DUAL_NOZZLES

// If you are using a 2nd EZOut V2 (connects to Y+ connector) filament sensor kit please follow the install guide
// and then uncomment the #define EZOUTV2_DUAL_ENABLE line below. Do NOT ever connect our filament sensor without the supplied adapter board.
//#define EZOUTV2_DUAL_ENABLE

// Use Ender Bootscreeen instead of TH3D
//#define ENDER_BOOT

//===========================================================================
// *************************  END PRINTER SECTION   *************************
//===========================================================================

//===========================================================================
// EZABL Advanced Settings
//===========================================================================

// If you want more or less EZABL probe points change the number below (only used if EZABL enabled)
// Default is 3 which gives you 3x3 grid for a total of 9 points. STICK WITH ODD NUMBERS
#define EZABL_POINTS 3

// If you want to probe in on the bed more than 15mm change this below. 
// Do not use 30mm for the Standard CR-10/s or the S4 as you will be on the bed screws.
// Try 50mm to avoid the binder clips if you use them. Do NOT go under 15mm here.
// You can do down to 10mm on the Wanhao i3 since it cannot print on the entire bed.
// You can do down to 5mm on the Wanhao i3 Mini since it cannot print on the entire bed.
// (only used if EZABL enabled)
#define EZABL_PROBE_EDGE 15

// If you have issues with your machine running the faster probe setting disable the #define EZABL_FASTPROBE below.
// DO NOTE: Most machines will work with the fast probe enabled. Use M48 to verify accuracy.
#define EZABL_FASTPROBE

// This will disable the XYE motors during probing. Can be useful if you have stepper motors causing interference issues with the EZABL sensor.
//#define PROBING_MOTORS_OFF

// Heaters will stay on during probing - only use if directed to by support. Do not use on AC beds.
#define HEATERS_ON_DURING_PROBING

// Letting the bed heat recover between probes can increase accuracy due to the bed warping during cooling/heating
// Enabling the below option will let the bed get back to temperature during probing but will increase probing times.
//#define WAIT_FOR_BED_HEATER

// If you want a more granular control over the babystepping uncomment the below line.
// This will make the adjustment finer than the standard setting.
//#define FINE_BABYSTEPPING

// This will extrapolate the implied tilt of the bed outside of the probe area. Do not comment out unless directed by support.
#define EZABL_OUTSIDE_GRID_COMPENSATION

// Does your machine make weird noises/vibrations when it is probing the mesh? Enable this to slow down the speed between probe points.
//#define SLOWER_PROBE_MOVES

//================================================================================
// IF YOU HAVE A CUSTOM PROBE MOUNT OR ONE THAT IS NOT PRE-SUPPORTED UNCOMMENT THE
// CUSTOM_PROBE OPTION IN YOUR PRINTER SECTION AND ENTER YOUR PROBE LOCATION BELOW
//================================================================================
#if ENABLED(CUSTOM_PROBE)
  /**
  *   Z Probe to nozzle (X,Y) offset, relative to (0, 0).
  *   X and Y offsets must be whole numbers.
  *
  *   In the following example the X and Y offsets are both positive:
  *   #define X_PROBE_OFFSET_FROM_EXTRUDER 10
  *   #define Y_PROBE_OFFSET_FROM_EXTRUDER 10
  *
  *      +-- BACK ---+
  *      |           |
  *    L |    (+) P  | R <-- probe (10,10)
  *    E |           | I
  *    F | (-) N (+) | G <-- nozzle (0,0)
  *    T |           | H
  *      |    (-)    | T
  *      |           |
  *      O-- FRONT --+
  *    (0,0)
  */
  #define X_PROBE_OFFSET_FROM_EXTRUDER -44  // X offset: -left  +right  [of the nozzle]
  #define Y_PROBE_OFFSET_FROM_EXTRUDER -7  // Y offset: -front +behind [the nozzle]
#endif

//===========================================================================
//******************** EXTRA FEATURES AND TWEAKS ****************************
//===========================================================================

// TH3D RGB LED STRIP ------------------------------
// If you are using the TH3D RGB strip connect to the Z+ endstop connection, power supply connection, and uncomment the below line
//#define TH3D_RGB_STRIP
// If you cut the strip shorter please count the LEDs that are left, uncomment the line below, and change the number below to how many LEDs you have.
#define TH3D_RGB_STRIP_LED_COUNT 20

// EXTRUDER SETTINGS -------------------------------

// If you want to change the Esteps for your printer you can uncomment the below line and set CUSTOM_ESTEPS_VALUE to what you want - USE WHOLE NUMBERS ONLY
#define CUSTOM_ESTEPS
#define CUSTOM_ESTEPS_VALUE 138

// If you are using an TH3D Tough Extruder, Bondtech BMG (set steps below to 415), or E3D Titan Extruder
// uncomment the below line to setup the firmware to the correct steps and direction. Also applicable to Titan/Tough Aero setups.
//#define TITAN_EXTRUDER
#define TITAN_EXTRUDER_STEPS 463

// DUAL HOTEND SETTINGS ----------------------------

// This is the distance between each nozzle tip when using a dual hotend like the TH3D Tough Dual Hotend or the E3D Chimera or Dual hotends.
// This setting only applies to printers using a dual extruder board.
#define DUAL_HOTEND_X_DISTANCE 18.0

// THERMISTOR SETTINGS -----------------------------

// If you are using an E3D V6 Hotend with their cartridge thermistor (not glass version) uncomment the below line.
//#define V6_HOTEND

// If you are using a Tough Hotend from TH3D or any thermistors TH3D sells for your hotend uncomment the below line.
//#define TH3D_HOTEND_THERMISTOR

// If you are using a thermistor TH3D sells for your bed uncomment the below line.
//#define TH3D_BED_THERMISTOR

// If you are using a Keenovo with SSR and the Keenovo temperature sensor uncomment the below line.
//#define KEENOVO_TEMPSENSOR

// If you are using a known hotend thermistor value uncomment the below 2 lines and enter the thermistor number replacing the X after the #define KNOWN_HOTEND_THERMISTOR_VALUE
//#define KNOWN_HOTEND_THERMISTOR
//#define KNOWN_HOTEND_THERMISTOR_VALUE X

// If you are using a known bed thermistor value uncomment the below 2 lines and enter the thermistor number replacing the X after the #define KNOWN_BED_THERMISTOR_VALUE
//#define KNOWN_BED_THERMISTOR
//#define KNOWN_BED_THERMISTOR_VALUE X

// If you want to make thermal protection periods less or more adjust below. The number is in seconds.
// If you are getting false thermal runaway then increase the protection time. Do not make it over 300 for either setting.
#define HOTEND_THERMAL_PROTECTION_TIME 60
#define BED_THERMAL_PROTECTION_TIME 180

// BED SETTINGS ------------------------------------

// If you want PID tuning on your bed you can enable the below line. But PID on a bed is not typically needed. By default BED PID is disabled.
// This will be disabled when using automatic or manual mesh leveling with a 1284p board due to memory limitations.
//#define PIDBED_ENABLE

// If you are using an AC bed with a standalone controller (Keenovo) uncomment the below line to disable the heated bed in the firmware
//#define AC_BED

// Stock bed max is 120C for this firmware. Enable this to allow temps up to 150C. Your bed must support this temp for it to achieve the higher temperatures.
//#define BED_HIGHTEMP

// MISC --------------------------------------------

// If you have a 5015 fan that whines when under 100% speed uncomment the below line.
//#define FAN_FIX

// Use your own printer name
//#define USER_PRINTER_NAME "Ender 3" 

// If your printer is homing to the endstops hard uncomment this to change the homing speed/divisor to make it less aggressive.
//#define SLOWER_HOMING

// BOOT SCREEN OPTIONS -----------------------------

// Use TinyMachines Bootscreen instead of TH3D
//#define TM3D_BOOT

// Disable Bootscreen completely
#define DISABLE_BOOT

//===========================================================================
//****************** COMMUNITY REQUESTED FEATURES ***************************
//===========================================================================

// HOME OFFSET ADJUSTMENT --------------------------
// If you need to adjust your XY home offsets from defaults then you can uncomment the HOME_ADJUST_LOCATION line below and enter your
// custom XY offsets. This is provided for convenience and is unsupported with included product support.
// How to use - measure (home XY then jog using the LCD 1mm at a time) the X and Y distance the nozzle is off
// the build plate and then put those as NEGATIVE values below, positive values will NOT work (move your endstops to fix a positve offset).
//#define HOME_ADJUST
#define X_HOME_ADJUST_LOCATION -10
#define Y_HOME_ADJUST_LOCATION -10

// LINEAR ADVANCE ----------------------------------
// See here on how to use Linear Advance: http://marlinfw.org/docs/features/lin_advance.html
//
//#define LINEAR_ADVANCE
// Change the K Value here or use M900 KX.XX in your starting code (recommended).
#define LINEAR_ADVANCE_K 0
// NOTE: If using linear advance along with EZABL on a printer with 1284p some Control > Motion menus will not be displayed due to space restrictions.
// You can still change these via GCode commands.

// BL TOUCH ----------------------------------------
// If you want to use the BL-Touch install your EZOut Board, uncomment the 2 lines below, uncomment the CUSTOM_PROBE option in your printer section, 
// and then enter your probe offsets in the CUSTOM_PROBE section above. The Pin 27 boards on eBay are clones of our original EZOut. If you want to 
// support the people that originally came up with the board you can get our EZOut breakout board here: http://EZOut.TH3DStudio.com
// Sales from our shop allow us to allocate time for community firmware development at no charge to you. <3
// If you have a V3 BL Touch also uncomment the BLTOUCH_V3 line to fix issues with the new V3 probe.
//
#define BLTOUCH
#define BLTOUCH_V3
// Here is where you set your servo pin. EZOut Servo Pin Numbers: Ender3/5/CR-10 - 27, Ender 2 - 29. For 2560 boards look for the pin you connected the servo wire to and enter below.
#define SERVO0_PIN 27
//
// NOTE: On 1284p boards due to space limitations and the large amount of code the BLTouch requires for the LCD Menus
// the Bootscreen and some Control > Motion menus will not be displayed due to space restrictions

// MANUAL MESH LEVELING ----------------------------
// If you want to use manual mesh leveling you can enable the below option. This is for generating a MANUAL mesh WITHOUT a probe. 
// Mesh Bed Leveling Documentation: http://marlinfw.org/docs/gcode/G029-mbl.html If used with a 1284P board the bootscreen will be disabled to save space.
// NOTE: If you want to automate the leveling process our EZABL kits do this for you. Check them out here: http://EZABL.TH3DStudio.com
//#define MANUAL_MESH_LEVELING

// POWER LOSS RECOVERY -----------------------------
// Continue after Power-Loss feature will store the current state to the SD Card at the start of each layer
// during SD printing. If this is found at bootup it will ask you if you want to resume the print.
//
// NOTE: This feature causes excessive wear on your SD card. This will disable junction jerk,  SCurve Acceleration, and Linear Advance due to RAM limitations.
//#define POWER_LOSS_RECOVERY

// MOTION SETTINGS ---------------------------------
// There are 2 new acceleration/jerk controls available in this firmware that can result is better print quality and
// smoother movement. To try each out just enable them below.
// Due to Anet board restrictions this is always disabled on those machines.
//#define JUNCTION_DEVIATION_ON
//#define S_CURVE_ACCELERATION_ON

//================================================================================================
// Language - This is provided for convenience and is unsupported with included product support.
// We only test compile with English language. If you run into space issues disable some features.
//================================================================================================

/**
 * LCD LANGUAGE
 *
 * Select the language to display on the LCD. These languages are available:
 *
 *    en, an, bg, ca, cn, cz, cz_utf8, de, el, el-gr, es, eu, fi, fr, fr_utf8, gl,
 *    hr, it, kana, kana_utf8, nl, pl, pt, pt_utf8, pt-br, pt-br_utf8, ru, sk_utf8,
 *    tr, uk, zh_CN, zh_TW, test
 */

#define LCD_LANGUAGE en

#include "Configuration_beta.h"
#include "Configuration_backend.h"

#define UNIFIED_VERSION "TH3D U1.R2.15"

#endif // CONFIGURATION_H
```

**Cura Start GCode**

```
M201 X500.00 Y500.00 Z100.00 E5000.00 ;Setup machine max acceleration
M203 X500.00 Y500.00 Z10.00 E50.00 ;Setup machine max feedrate
M204 P500.00 R1000.00 T500.00 ;Setup Print/Retract/Travel acceleration
M205 X8.00 Y8.00 Z0.40 E5.00 ;Setup Jerk
M220 S100 ;Reset Feedrate
M221 S100 ;Reset Flowrate

G28 G29 ;Home

G92 E0 ;Reset Extruder
G1 Z2.0 F3000 ;Move Z Axis up
G1 X10.1 Y20 Z0.28 F5000.0 ;Move to start position
G1 X10.1 Y200.0 Z0.28 F1500.0 E15 ;Draw the first line
G1 X10.4 Y200.0 Z0.28 F5000.0 ;Move to side a little
G1 X10.4 Y20 Z0.28 F1500.0 E30 ;Draw the second line
G92 E0 ;Reset Extruder
G1 Z2.0 F3000 ;Move Z Axis up
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

G-code is read line-by-line, see e.g. [Is G-code read line by line?](/q/7417). If the posted start G-code is the actual used G-code, `G29` is not executed because it is on the same line as `G28`. This means that in:

```
G28 G29 ;Home
```

`G29` simply is ignored (it is not recognised by the interpreter as parameters for `G28`). This should be changed into:

```
G28 ;Home
G29 ;Perform bed leveling
```

Comment: Ahh!! yes of course! I even knew that so I should have spotted that myself. I think I just blindly copied the G28 G29 on one line from somewhere... I think it was the creality BL Touch instruction sheet that came in the box with the BL Touch! I'll give this a try later today... thank you!